# Lie algebra homomorphism preserves Jordan form

Tags: lie-algebras

**Fact** : $\phi : L_1\rightarrow L_2$ is $surjective$
Lie algebra
             homomorphism. If $h\in L_1$ and ${\rm ad}_h$ is diagonalizable
             then ${\rm ad}_{\phi(h)}$ is diagonalizable

**Defn** $x\in {\rm gl}\ ({\bf C}^n)$ has **Jordan** decomposition if $$
x= d+n $$ where $[d,n]=0$, $d$ is diagonalizable and $n$ is
nilpotent.

**EXE** (cf. 90page in Erdmann and Wildon's book)  If under the same assumption in the above fact $L_i$ are complex semisimples and if
             $$ x=d+n$$ is Jordan, then we have Jordan $$ \varphi x=
             \varphi d + \varphi n $$

**Proof** : Commutativeness : $$ [\phi d, \phi n] = \phi
[dn]=0$$

**Question** : I cannot prove "Diagonalizability of $\varphi d$ and nilpotency of $\varphi n$"

**My try** : $ {\rm ad}_x$ has Jordan That
is $$ {\rm ad}_x = {\rm ad}_{d'} + {\rm ad}_{n'},\ d',\ n'\in L_1 $$
Note that we have Lie algebra homomorphism $$ \Phi : {\rm ad} \ L_1
\rightarrow {\rm ad}\ L_2,\ \Phi\ ({\rm ad}_y) = {\rm ad}_{\phi y}$$
 and $$ {\rm ad}_{\phi x} = {\rm ad}_{\phi d'} + {\rm ad}_{\phi n'}
$$ where $[{\rm ad}_{\phi d'}, {\rm ad}_{\phi n'}]=0$, and ${\rm ad}_{\phi d'}$ is diagonalizable.

And note that $ {\rm ad}_{\varphi n'} $ is nilpotent : Since $$ 0=
\varphi (0) = \varphi [ ({\rm ad}_{n'})^k(y) ] = \varphi [ n',\
\cdots, [n',y]\cdots]=[\varphi n',\cdots, [ \varphi n', \varphi
y]\cdots ] = ({\rm ad}_{\varphi n'})^k (\varphi y) $$ ${\rm
ad}_{\varphi n'}$ is nilpotent.

My try is right ? I need helpful comment Thank you !

Comment: You have also to show that $\phi (d)$ and $\phi(n)$ are again in $L_2$. Here you need that $L_2$ is semisimple, over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487384/does-the-abstract-jordan-decomposition-agree-with-the-usual-jordan-decomposition/487569#487569.