# Basis of Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

With the matrices below, apparently $\{u_k = -\frac i2 \lambda_k| k=1,2,\cdots,8\}$ forms a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$

[image]

How could that be true? $-\frac i2 \lambda_1$ shouldn't even be an element of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, it isn't hermitian.

Comment: Why are you adding a factor $-\frac{i}{2}$ everywhere? That seems odd.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How could it? A Lie algebra is in particular a vector space, so scalars will not change whether some matrix is in the Lie algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can I just have your clarification on what they would likely mean for a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$? I originally assumed it was a vectorspace basis, but it seems to be something else then?

Comment: The matrices $u_i=-i/2\lambda_i$ do satisfy $x^{\ast}=-x$, so everything is OK.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But while these basis elements do satisfy that condition, not all the elements do, as the condition is not preserved by linear combinations, so the description mentioned is not the correct one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Isn't multiplying by $i$ (or by $-i/2)$  a linear isomorphism from Hermitian matrices to anti-Hermitian matrices ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since neither class of matrices form a vector space, I am not sure what you mean by a linear isomorphism. Or are we taking things as real vector spaces here?

Comment: Well they did all satisfy anti-hermitian, which was what was required(I originally thought hermitian was the requirement for $\mathfrak{u}$)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, exactly,  as a real vector space. $SU(n)$ is a real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is explained [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QFjACahUKEwj9m-KjqbLHAhXB1RQKHSonDSw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fworkspace.imperial.ac.uk%2Ftheoreticalphysics%2Fpublic%2FMSc%2FPartSymm%2FSU(3)Notes.pdf&ei=ZPvSVf3ZN8GrU6rOtOAC&usg=AFQjCNEBrmkpec6harhh8sWGK3ep03MwOQ&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGg) as follows: the $8$-dimensional real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ has a basis $\lambda_1,\ldots ,\lambda_8$ as above, consisiting of Hermitian matrices. However, the Lie bracket of this subspace of $3\times 3$ matrices is **not** given by the commutator $AB-BA$, because the commutator of two Hermitian matrices is *not* Hermitian again in general. Of course, we could insist on a different Lie bracket given by $[A,B]=i(AB-BA)$. However, a more popular solution is to pass to **anti-Hermitian** matrices, which gives an isomorphic Lie algebra, but this time with the more natural Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$. For a similar discussion on MSE, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391106/meaning-of-a-b-when-a-and-b-are-self-adjoint/1391139#1391139).