# infinitesimal generator of SU(3)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have computed generator infinitesimal of SU(3), i got 8 generator
$$
X_1= {\begin{pmatrix}  0& 1&0\\ 1& 0&0\\0&0&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_2= {\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0&1\\ 0& 0&0\\1&0&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_3= {\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0&0\\ 0& 0&1\\0&1&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_4= {\begin{pmatrix} 0& -i&0\\ i& 0&0\\0&0&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_5= {\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0&-i\\ 0& 0&0\\i&0&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_6= {\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0&0\\ 0& 0&-i\\0&i&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_7= {\begin{pmatrix} -1& 0&0\\ 0& 1&0\\0&0&0  \end{pmatrix}}\\
X_8= {\begin{pmatrix} -1& 0&0\\ 0& 0&0\\0&0&1  \end{pmatrix}}\\
$$
but apparently when i check in the internet, the last 2 generator , that is $X_7$ and $X_8$ is wrong
i calculate it by defining tranformation $T$ near the identity and so on.
my question is why the last two generator is wrong

Comment: Do your $X_7$ and $X_8$ span the same subspace as the ones you find on the Internet?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401246/basis-of-lie-algebra-mathfraksu3).

Answer (score 1):

Your matrices are just fine, and just as linearly independent as the eight [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices).

So, just a minor change of basis,
$$
X_1=\lambda_1 \qquad X_2=\lambda_4 \qquad  X_3=\lambda_6 \qquad  X_4=\lambda_2   \\
X_5=\lambda_5 \qquad X_6=\lambda_7 \qquad X_7=-\lambda_3 \qquad 
X_8=-\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_3 +\sqrt{3} ~ \lambda_8). 
$$