# How to prove that $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)$ is a simple Lie algebra for $n\ge 2$?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

The goal is to prove directly that $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)$ is a simple Lie algebra for $n \ge 2$

So far I'm trying to think of ways to show that there are no non-trivial ideals (definition of simple) for $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)$, where $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)$ is the collection of all matrices which have trace $= 0$.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around Lie algebras, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: quick googling yields https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~plyung/simplicity_sln.pdf some linear algebra knowledge required, but the proof is more or less self-contained

Comment: Here's a link to a proof for the case $n=2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409941/55622