# Computational proof showing $sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ is simple?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Computational proof showing $sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ is simple?

Showing that $sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ is simple has been asked a few times here, and people are saying that there are some computational ways of proving this and some that are a bit more conceptual. People have provided links to certain proofs by Po-Lam Yung Crystal Hoyt that are more conceptual, but I can't find any references for a more direct computational approach. I would like to see such.

Can somebody give me a free reference? I'm poor$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the computational proof by Po-Lam Yung [here](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Eplyung/simplicity_sln.pdf), or at these MSE posts:

[How to prove that $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\Bbb C)$ is a simple Lie algebra for $n\ge 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451489/how-to-prove-that-mathfraksln-bbb-c-is-a-simple-lie-algebra-for-n-ge-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to show that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are simple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598356/how-to-show-that-mathfraksl-n-mathbbr-and-mathfraksl-n-mathbbc)

Both is for $0$ USD.