# Is Lie algebra sl(n;F) simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

If we assume field $F$ has characteristic $p$, can we get the statement that $sl(n;F)$ is a simple Lie algebra? Here integer $n$ is not a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1598356/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467539/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1409744/96384 and possibly more.

Comment: Yes, I have read them, but my question is more general. Is there some references to get an answer for the more general question?

Comment: The proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467539/mathfraksl3-f-is-simple?noredirect=1&lq=1) does work for all $n\ge 3$, too. A reference is the book by George Seligman on modular Lie algebras.