# $su(2) $ and $ sl(2;R)$ are not isomorphic?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

As real Lie algebras, both are three-dimensional. The basis of $su(2)$ is

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i  \end{matrix} \right), \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0  \end{matrix} \right),\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0  \end{matrix} \right) . $$

The basis of $sl(2;R)$ is

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1  \end{matrix} \right), \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{matrix} \right),\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0  \end{matrix} \right) . $$

But how to prove that there is no isomorphism mapping between the two algebras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first of these has no two-dimensional subalgebras, whereas the second does. See [$\mathfrak{su}(2)$ not isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466917) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/550303)

Comment: Why does it not answer the question? Any isomorphism would map a two-dimensional subalgebra to a two-dimensional subalgebra.

Comment: The language was a copy-paste, don't get disheartened at that. The point is:  This better suits to be a comment than an answer since this does not have a proper explanation or links to backup. You might say this requires no explanation, its totally straightforward ; but the general trend shows people asking such questions often get confused by $1$ line answers. No offence intended to the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As you guessed I posted it as an answer as I couldn't post it as a comment. I've since seen that a fuller explanation is given in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466917.

Comment: You're welcome.