# SU(1,1) isomorphic to SL(2,R), but SU(2) is not

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, linear-groups

I am surprised by the fact that $\mathrm{SU}(1, 1)$ group is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, but $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$.

The first statement is easy to prove. An element of $\mathrm{SU}(1, 1)$ is

$$g=\left[\begin{array}{cc} \alpha & \beta \\  \beta^* &  \alpha^* \end{array}\right] =\left[\begin{array}{cc} x+iy & z+id\\ z-id &  x-iy \end{array}\right] \quad , |\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1.$$

The mapping to  $p=\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\  c &  d \end{array}\right] \in  \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, $(ad-bc=1) $ is
$$a=x-d, \quad b=z-y, \quad c=y+z, \quad d=x+d.$$
The second fact is well known and discussed here [SU(2) and SL(2,R) are not isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590601/su2-and-sl2r-are-not-isomorphic)

Is there any intuitive way to understand why $\mathrm{SU}(1, 1)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ are so different in such respect?

Comment: Isn't $|\alpha|^2 - |\beta|^2 = 1$ very different from $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$?

Comment: Yes, it is different. But, can we map an element of SU(1,1) to SU(2) to make it the same?

Comment: I just guess that there should be a mapping from SU(1,1) to SU(2)..Or no?

Comment: A mapping, yes, but not a "good" one like a group isomorphism.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde. I always thought that two groups are isomorphic iff exists a bijective one-to-one map between the elements. Am I mistaken, and is it not enough?

Comment: $G\cong H$ iff there is a bijective one-to-one mapping $f\colon G\rightarrow H$ satisfying $f(gh)=f(g)f(h)$, so in addition being a *group homomorphism*. Did you find a group isomorphism between $SU(1,1)$ and $SU(2)$ as you wanted? (" I just guess that there should be a mapping from...").

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, thank you for your important note on group homomorphism and $f(gh)=f(g)f(h)$. This is where I was stuck and made mistake.

Comment: Consider $SO(2)$ vs $SO^+(1,1)$. One is a compact circle, the other is an unbounded hyperbola. As a Lie group the latter is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+)$, which has no torsion. Every element of the former is either torsion or generates a dense subgroup. Pretty different.

Answer (score 4):

The group $SU(2)$ is compact, whereas $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ isn't. That's enough to make a huge difference. And $SU(2)$ is compact because the condition that defines it ($|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$) assures that it is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb C^{2\times2}$. Clearly, $SU(1,1)$ is *un*bounded.

Answer (score 2):

The set $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ is compact, but not $|a|^2-|b|^2=1$