# Is the semisimple part of $x \in L$ belong to $L$ when $L$ is a semisimple Lie algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over a field of charcteristic $0$ and algebraically closed. I have learned that the map 
$$
ad: L \rightarrow \  Der(L)
$$
is an isompsphism, where $adx(y) = [x,y]$ and $Der(L)$ denotes all the derivations on $L$. Furthermore, I have learned that if $x \in L$ is semisimple then $adx:L \rightarrow L$ is semisimple. I was wondering from these information does it actually follow that $x_s \in L$? (where $x_s$ is the unique semisimple part of $x$)

Clarification: Given  $x \in L$ we can always write it as $x = x_s + x_n$ where $x_s$ is the semisimple part and $x_n$ is the nilpotent part and I know that they both lie in $gl(V)$ but do they lie in $L$? 
(and I am viewing $L$ as a subalgebra of $gl(V)$ for some finite dimensional vector space $V$)

Comment: I think this is true; this seems to follow from the fact that $L$ is the Lie algebra of an algebraic group. Probably there's then a more direct proof. This is maybe done in Bourbaki.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487384/does-the-abstract-jordan-decomposition-agree-with-the-usual-jordan-decomposition?rq=1).

Comment: This is definitely done in Bourbaki, for any field of characteristic $0$, and probably in most other sources at least for $\Bbb C$. See Dietrich Burde's link and comments for an exact reference. Note that if you view $L$ as subalgebra of "some" $gl(V)$ you should worry about that being independent of the choice of $V$ (which it is, but that's part of the proof).